# Как получить параметр code при Authorizing OAuth Apps GitHub?

Tags: github, oauth

Выполняю по клику такую штуку,

```
const onClickLogin = (): void => {
  window.open(
    `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize/?client_id=${clientID}`
  );
};
```

авторизацию как бы прохожу при ридеректе в url вижу параметр code, как его получить?
что бы дальше уже получить токен.

На своей страничке GitHub создал OAuth Apps, получил client_id.
По настройке аутентификации пользуюсь (как уж получается) https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#1-request-a-users-github-identity
И еще одно, как прохожу аутентификацию хочу закрыть данное окно и вернуться обратно, как то так.

Подскажите, куда дальше копать.

Answer (score 0):

`if (window.location.search.match(/code/)) { const code = window.location.search.replace("?code=", ""); document.cookie = "responseCodeGitHub=" + code; }`
Как то так вышло, в store это отлавливаю.